# Application crash when have string double bar

Tags: android

im new in android and java, im trying use this string

```
String textSource = "https://sites.google.com/site/androidersite/text.txt";
```

But my app stop working. If i remove the "//" from the string work fine.
How can i use the "//" in my string?.
thanks

here is my code:

```
public void Conectar(String miStr){

        String textResult;
        String textSource = "https://sites.google.com/site/androidersite/text.txt";

        Toast.makeText(c, "test: " + textSource, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        URL textUrl;

            try {
                textUrl = new URL("https://"+textSource);

                BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(
                        new InputStreamReader(textUrl.openStream()));

                String stringBuffer;
                String stringText = "";
                while((stringBuffer = bufferReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    stringText += stringBuffer;
                }

                bufferReader.close();
                textResult = stringText;
                Toast.makeText(c, "ojala: " + textResult, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } catch(MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            } catch(IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                textResult = e.toString();
            }
            //return null;
    }
```

The problem is the String i dont know why the "//" in textSource i making my app crash

i try the answer using

```
textUrl = new URL("https://sites.google.com/site/androidersite/text.txt");
String textSource = textUrl.toString();
```

but still crash

here is my logcat

```
11-10 16:30:10.707  11694-11694/? I/art﹕ Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
11-10 16:30:11.056  11694-11715/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
11-10 16:30:11.063  11694-11694/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 D/Atlas﹕ Validating map...
11-10 16:30:11.155  11694-11715/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM build: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020_msm8960_LA.AF.1.1_RB1__release_AU ()
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.25.03.06
    Build Date: 03/30/15 Mon
    Local Branch: mybranch8688311
    Remote Branch: quic/LA.AF.1.1_rb1.16
    Local Patches: NONE
    Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LA.AF.1.1_RB1.05.00.02.006.020 + 9b2699f + 2215637 + 60aa592 + f2362e6 + 5c64f59 + 82411a1 + 1f36e07 +  NOTHING
11-10 16:30:11.156  11694-11715/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4
11-10 16:30:11.184  11694-11715/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
11-10 16:30:17.291  11694-11694/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
11-10 16:30:17.294  11694-11694/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.testusr.calculadora1, PID: 11694
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:278)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
     Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
            at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1161)
            at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:252)
            at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:215)
            at com.android.okhttp.HostResolver$1.getAllByName(HostResolver.java:29)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:232)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:124)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:272)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:211)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:382)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:332)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:199)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:210)
            at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
            at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:470)
            at com.example.testusr.calculadora1.Conexion.Conectar(Conexion.java:48)
            at com.example.testusr.calculadora1.MainActivity.btnBuscarClic(MainActivity.java:84)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at android.support.v7.internal.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:273)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4785)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19884)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)
11-10 16:30:18.690  11694-11694/com.example.testusr.calculadora1 I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 11694 SIG: 9
```

Comment: How your app stop working? Show logCat? And show code?

Comment: your app is crashing cause your trying a network operation on the main thread run this in a new thread off the UI or asynctask

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make the `textSource` be the `URL`? Then when you want it to be a string:

```
URL textSource = new URL("https://sites.google.com/site/androidersite/text.txt");
String urlStr = textSource.toString(); // or use .toString() wherever you need it to be a string
```